# No consigo activar el sign In con google y firebase en mi app

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin, firebase-auth

Hola estoy intentando configurar el login con google en firebase pero no me funciona. Este es el código de la autenticación con google:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 100

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        //Setup
        setup()
        session()
    }

    private fun setup() {
        googleLoginButton.setOnClickListener {
            //Configuracion
            val googleConf = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build()

            val googleClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleConf)
            googleClient.signOut()

            startActivityForResult(googleClient.signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
        }
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {

            val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)

            try{
                val account: GoogleSignInAccount? = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!

                if (account != null) {

                    val credential: AuthCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken, null)

                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener{
                        if (it.isSuccessful) {
                            showHome(account.email ?: "", ProviderType.GOOGLE)
                        } else {
                            authAlert()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                authAlert2()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

El problema debe estar en el try, ya que me muestra el texto que tengo configurado en la función authAlert2().

Hay mas funciones en el archivo pero no las añado porque no tienen que ver con la autenticación con google o porque lo que hacen es mostrar popups de error.

Espero que me puedan ayudar, soy muy nuevo en programación y esto lo hice siguiendo un tutorial por lo que hay algunas cosas que no entiendo bien.

Comment: Que se muestra como error, podrìas especificar, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: No me da ningún error, simplemente no realiza el registro, por eso no se que está pasando.

Comment: Deberías imprimir el error debajo de esta línea  } catch (e: ApiException) { y revisar el LogCat